# Cookie to redirect to splash page

Tags: redirect, cookies, splash-screen, visited

First off, I'd like to say that I'm very new to javascript, jquery and/or php. Of the latter I know nothing and the other two aren't far from that.

That being said, I have been scouring the internet for many hours on too many occasions to count for this (admittedly somewhat specific and yet so widely used) thing. It seems to me as though redirecting people to a splash page with a cookie is as well-kept a secret as the recipe for Coca-Cola.

What I want is rather simple, I thought. When the visitor goes to my website, they arrive at the index.html (as per usual). I want to implement a cookie onto this page that applies itself to the visitor. It must check whether the visitor has been to the site before or not. If not, it redirects to splash.html instead. The splash page will be used for the visitor to select the language in which he/she wishes to view the website with links to other HTML pages - this I can make. I have found some snippets here and there, but the javascript seemed too complicated and to always have something missing, somehow, to be able to apply to me and function properly.

Please help!

To recapitulate:

> Visitor loads index.html
>
> Cookie acknowledges
>
> ```
> if visited before
> ```
>
> Do nothing
>
> ```
> else
> ```
>
> Redirect to splash.html

Seriously, thank you to anyone who can help me with this.

Also, any help as to where to learn Javascript from absolute scratch easily is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to do this using only Javascript (on client side), without involving server side? Does your website use PHP already or is it just a set of plain HTML pages?

Comment: I don't particularly mind how it works in case PHP is noticeably easier but for now, I would prefer javascript, since I seem to be able to read that more easily. My site is only a set of HTML pages so far and I would like to keep it that way. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this solution works for what I need:

```
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'splash-page-cookie';
    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    if ($go == null) {
        $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: 183 });
        window.location = "Splash.html"
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

This script works with the Carhartl Jquery cookie plugin.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a good article on working with cookies in Javascript at Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

What should help you is [Example #3<sub>bis</sub>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Example_.233bis.3A_Do_something_only_once_.E2.80.93_simplified_code):

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)someCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
}
```

When you get the value of `document.cookie`, you get the semicolon-separated list of cookies. The regular expression in the first line finds the value of cookie named `someCookieName`.

When you set the value of `document.cookie`, you set or update one cookie (you don't overwrite the whole list of cookies as it may look)

In order to redirect a visitor, you can use [`document.location` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.location).

The following code should do what you need:

```
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)seenSplash\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    document.cookie = "seenSplash=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
    document.location = "/splash.html";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and consistent response. I have to say, though, that I don't fully understand how that works. Do I simply use the code you've given me, that you said should do what I need by putting it in the head tag of my html file, then upload it to my FTP server and it should work? I get the feeling something might be missing still; though I checked the developer.mozilla.org link you provided me with (thank you, by the way - very complete-looking source), I could not discover what.

Comment: Wrap the code in `script` tag, put inside `head` and it should work.